# Fails to compile on using the kendo-react-grid's typescript implementation

Tags: reactjs, typescript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-react-ui

Fails to compile on using the simplest of grid implementations as follows. (But the same works on a react JS implementation)
Code is as follows for the react component.

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as redux from 'redux';
import * as projectActions from '../../redux/actions/projectActions';
import * as authorActions from '../../redux/actions/authorActions';
import * as React from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { Project } from '../../interfaces/Project';
import { ApplicationState } from '../../redux/reducers/initialState';
import { Grid } from '@Progress/kendo-react-grid';
​
interface OwnProps {
​
}
​
​
type ReduxProps = ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps> & ReturnType<typeof mapDispatchToProps>;
// type Props = StateFromProps & DispatchFromProps & NavbarComponentProps;
interface Pprops extends ReduxProps {
    handleDeleteProject1: (project: Project) => void
}
​
class ProjectsPage extends React.Component<Pprops, any> {
​
    state = {
        redirectToAddProjectPage: false
    };
​
    componentDidMount() {
    }
​
    handleDeleteProject1 = async (project: Project) => {
    }
​
    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <Grid></Grid>
            </>
        );
    }
}
​
function mapStateToProps(
    state: ApplicationState
    , ownProps: OwnProps
) {
    const projectsList = state.projectsStateSlice.projects;
    return {
        projects:
            projectsList.map(project => {
                const authorNamee = project.authorId.toString();
                return {
                    ...project,
                    authorName: authorNamee
                };
            }),
        authors: state.authorsStateSlice.authors,
        loading: 0
    };
}
​
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: redux.Dispatch) {
    return {
        actions: {
            loadProjects: bindActionCreators(projectActions.loadProjects, dispatch),
            loadAuthors: bindActionCreators(authorActions.loadAuthors, dispatch),
            deleteProject: bindActionCreators(projectActions.deleteProject, dispatch)
        }
    };
}
​
// prop types declarations
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ProjectsPage);
​
```

My package.json is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "cncy-react-redux",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start:dev": "react-scripts start",
    "prestart:api": "node tools/createMockDb.js",
    "start:api": "node tools/apiServer.js",
    "test": "jest",
    "start": "run-p start:api start:dev"
  },
  "jest": {
    "setupFiles": [
      "./tools/testSetup.js"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|mp3|wav|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/tools/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/tools/styleMock.js"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.26",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.12.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.12.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.8",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.2.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "@types/bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "@types/enzyme": "^3.10.4",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.24",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.5",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.3",
    "@types/react-toastify": "^4.1.0",
    "@types/redux": "^3.6.0",
    "@types/redux-immutable-state-invariant": "^2.1.1",
    "@types/redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "@types/reselect": "^2.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "immer": "2.1.3",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "prop-types": "15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.16",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.0",
    "react-toastify": "^5.4.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-immutable-state-invariant": "^2.1.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0",
    "typescript": "~3.7.2",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "1.5.2",
    "@progress/kendo-date-math": "1.5.1",
    "@progress/kendo-drawing": "1.6.0",
    "@progress/kendo-react-animation": "3.9.0",
    "@progress/kendo-react-buttons": "3.9.0",
    "@progress/kendo-react-data-tools": "^3.9.0",
    "@progress/kendo-react-dateinputs": "3.9.0",
    "@progress/kendo-react-dialogs": "3.9.0",
    "@progress/kendo-react-dropdowns": "3.9.0",
    "@progress/kendo-react-excel-export": "3.9.0",
    "@progress/kendo-react-grid": "3.9.0",
    "@progress/kendo-react-inputs": "3.9.0",
    "@progress/kendo-react-intl": "3.9.0",
    "@progress/kendo-react-layout": "3.9.0",
    "@progress/kendo-react-pdf": "3.9.0",
    "@progress/kendo-react-popup": "3.9.0",
    "react-transition-group": "4.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "enzyme": "^3.9.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.11.2",
    "fetch-mock": "^8.1.0",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "json-server": "0.14.2",
    "node-fetch": "^2.3.0",
    "npm-run-all": "4.1.5",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.4",
    "react-testing-library": "^6.1.2",
    "redux-immutable-state-invariant": "2.1.0",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.3",
    "rimraf": "2.6.3",
    "style-loader": "0.23.1"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app",
    "settings": {
      "react": {
        "version": "detect"
      }
    },
    "root": true
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Throws the following error:

./src/components/projects/ProjectsPage.tsx
Cannot find file: 'main.js' does not match the corresponding name on disk: '.\node_modules@Progress\kendo-react-grid\dist\es@progress'.

When I dig into the node modules' directory that its claiming to throw the error from,

looks like this
.\node_modules@Progress\kendo-react-grid\dist\es\main.js

it doesn't apparently contain any directory called @progress inside of the es (.\node_modules@Progress\kendo-react-grid\dist\es@progress)

FYI: I also am a licensed developer.

Is this something to do with the licensing of the kendo UI by any chance?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This was too trivial. It was all about the wrong case I used inadvertently.
While importing the Grid control,

```
import { Grid } from '@Progress/kendo-react-grid';
```

It had to be @progress with "p" in lower case instead of @Progress.
That's it. But the error thrown would never have told me about this anyway.
Please be careful with the case.

Hope it helps someone.